# Can't get CSS Flex to act responsive. Divs going off screen

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am trying to create a simple layout that uses css flex to display 4 boxes across the screen on 2 rows.

What I want to happen is I want to be able to add more divs to my HTML, and whenever the divs reach the end of the right hand side of the screen, no more divs are added, and a new row should being.  However, whenever I add more than a certain number of divs, the divs start to move off screen. I want the divs to only stay within 100% of the screen size and move onto a NEW ROW once it hits the end of the page view.

The following photo shows what I am current getting and what I should be getting.

[image]

Here is some of my code....

HTML

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #212121;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  height: 100px;
  align-items: center;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 10px gold;
  background: #212121;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
}

.logoContainer,
.navLinks {
  display: flex;
}

.logoContainer {
  flex: 1;
}

nav {
  flex: 1;
}

.navLinks {
  justify-content: space-around;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 20px;
  color: white;
}

.navLink {
  font-size: 18px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.containers {
  display: flex;
  background: green;
}


.gold1,
.gold2,
.gold3,
.gold4,
.gold5 {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  flex: 1;
}

.title {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.price {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 40px;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
}
button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 35px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: rgb(14, 170, 14);
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.button {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="containers">
          <div class="gold1">
            <h1 class="title">shop 1</h1>
            <p class="price">$5</p>
            <div class="button">
              <button>Buy</button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="gold2">
            <h1 class="title">shop 2</h1>
            <p class="price">$5</p>
            <div class="button">
              <button>Buy</button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="gold3">
            <h1 class="title">shop 3</h1>
            <p class="price">$5</p>
            <div class="button">
              <button>Buy Gold</button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="gold4">
            <h1 class="title">shop 4</h1>
            <p class="price">$5</p>
            <div class="button">
              <button>Buy</button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="gold5">
            <h1 class="title">shop 5</h1>
            <p class="price">$5</p>
            <div class="button">
              <button>Buy</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

PLEASE NOTE : For some reason, the code snipet is not showing what my screen is showing. I will try to fix this.

As you can see a few things.

1. The boxes go off screen.
2. The boxes do not stack on each other as the screen get smaller ( I want this to be responsive, having all the boxes stack on top of each other 1 by 1 on smaller screens , and only showing 4 boxes / row on larger screens )

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add some extra flex properties to css to work fine

You do not need to create a class for each element if it is going to share its properties, if you want to add something you can create classes and add them to the element and to these add or remove properties. What I mean is that .gold1, .gold2, .gold3 ... etc. they are not really necessary you can only use .gold since all those boxes will share their css properties.

[CSS selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/CSS_Selector)

```
flex-direction: column; // for mobile devices
flex-wrap: wrap;
```

[Flexbox guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Also you need to use media queries to add or remove properties to your css id's,class,tags...

Here you can see an example of you want (Click on run code snippet and go to full page)

```css
body {
      background: #111;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    body>h1 {
      text-align: center;
      color: white;
    }

    .container {
      margin: auto;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      flex-direction: column;
      background: green;
      width: 90%;
    }

    .gold {
      background: white;
      border-radius: 10px;
      margin-top: 10px;
      padding: 10px;
    }

    .title {
      text-align: center;
      padding-top: 10px;
    }

    .price {
      text-align: center;
      margin-top: 40px;
      font-size: 24px;
      font-weight: bold;
      color: black;
    }

    .button {
      text-align: center;
      background-color: white;
    }

    button {
      width: 100px;
      height: 35px;
      border-radius: 10px;
      background: rgb(14, 170, 14);
      border: none;
      cursor: pointer;
      font-size: 16px;
    }

    @media (min-width: 992px) {
      .container {
        justify-content: space-between; /* add this */
        flex-direction: row; /* change direction */
        flex-wrap: wrap; /* wrap content */
      }

      .gold {
        width: 22%; /* assign a lower width */
      }
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Flex</h1>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="gold">
      <h1 class="title">Shop 1</h1>
      <p class="price">$5</p>
      <div class="button">
        <button>Button</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="gold">
      <h1 class="title">Shop 2</h1>
      <p class="price">$5</p>
      <div class="button">
        <button>Button</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="gold">
      <h1 class="title">Shop 3</h1>
      <p class="price">$5</p>
      <div class="button">
        <button>Button</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="gold">
      <h1 class="title">Shop 4</h1>
      <p class="price">$5</p>
      <div class="button">
        <button>Button</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="gold">
      <h1 class="title">Shop 5</h1>
      <p class="price">$5</p>
      <div class="button">
        <button>Button</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="gold">
      <h1 class="title">Shop 6</h1>
      <p class="price">$5</p>
      <div class="button">
        <button>Button</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="gold">
      <h1 class="title">Shop 7</h1>
      <p class="price">$5</p>
      <div class="button">
        <button>Button</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="gold">
      <h1 class="title">Shop 8</h1>
      <p class="price">$5</p>
      <div class="button">
        <button>Button</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="gold">
      <h1 class="title">Shop 9</h1>
      <p class="price">$5</p>
      <div class="button">
        <button>Button</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="gold">
      <h1 class="title">Shop 10</h1>
      <p class="price">$5</p>
      <div class="button">
        <button>Button</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="gold">
      <h1 class="title">Shop 11</h1>
      <p class="price">$5</p>
      <div class="button">
        <button>Button</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="gold">
      <h1 class="title">Shop 12</h1>
      <p class="price">$5</p>
      <div class="button">
        <button>Button</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I actually did remove all of those separate gold tags. I was using dummy images, and because they were different sizes, I needed to resize them. I fixed this by simple resizing images in figma, but thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. All I needed to do was add `flex-wrap: wrap` and it gave me the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

**use flex-direction row and then write flex-wrap:wrap in container class**